# how to get node using attribute value

Tags: xml

I want child nodes based on the attribute value..

how do I retrieve them like that?

Can anyone help me?

output:

text stuff..

But i need

```
<c>text</c>
<c>stuff</c>
```

code

```
  <?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
<b id="1">
<c>text</c>
<c>stuff</c>
</b>
<b name="title">
<c>code</c>
</b>
<d>
<c>item</c>
</d>
</a>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

    function getChildXML($xml, $tag, $id)
    {
        $output = '';
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($xml);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $elements = $xpath->query($tag . "[@id='$id']");
        foreach($elements as $element)
            $output .= $doc->saveXML($element);
        return $output;
    }

    echo getChildXML($string, 'b', 1);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the output right but if you are displaying it in browser use this

```
echo htmlentities(getChildXML($string, 'b', 1));
```

Comment: yes. thank you so much.. got it.. but i don want <b id="1">.. jus like above output..

Comment: change your code by replacing this `$elements = $xpath->query("b" . "[@id='$id']/c");`  i.e add `/c`